# RelativeLayout: Can't assign a view above a referenced view if margin is involved

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, margin, android-relativelayout

I was trying to put a TextView `dependent` above the other TextView `anchor` inside a RelativeLayout, but I can't manage to make the `dependent` get displayed.

**Situation:**
The `anchor` would be aligned with the parent's top + some *marginTop* to make it more to the center of the parent (RelativeLayout), and the `dependent` will be aligned to be above of this `anchor`.

This doesn't work; when I assigned it to be above the `anchor` it seems that android assumes the top of the `anchor` is the parent's top and draws the `dependent` outside the screen (above it).

This should not be the case since I use *margin* instead of *padding* so the area between the top of the RelativeLayout and the `anchor` shouldn't be the part of the `anchor` itself (I checked the size with hierarchy viewer). Or maybe I get it wrong? :S

This is the simple layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100px"
        android:text="Anchor point."
        />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/dependent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/anchor"
        android:text="Dependent."
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Desired:**

```
-------------
|           |
|dependent  |
|anchor     |
|           |
-------------
```

**What happened:**

```
dependent (out of screen display)
-------------
|           |
|           |
|anchor     |
|           |
-------------
```

**Hope:**
Could someone help me here? Or maybe help pointing out if I made a mistake. I need to use the RelativeLayout in my real implementation (above is just an example).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever figure this out ? I'm running into the same problem

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your comment. No, I don't know what went wrong here. In the end I made a hack using an empty view as a filler to replace the anchor's margin.

Comment: Yeah and I ended up margin-ing from the bottom the other view

Answer (score 1):

I made an invisible button to align from - is this what you're looking for? If you change the margin or any location parameter of the anchorbutton it will change the location of the dependants.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button android:id="@+id/anchorbutton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="100dp"
     android:visibility="invisible"
/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/anchor"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/anchorbutton"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@id/anchorbutton"
  android:layout_margin="10dp"
  android:text="Off Anchor button"
/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/dependent"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@id/anchorbutton"
  android:layout_below="@id/anchor"
  android:layout_margin="50dp"
  android:text="Dependent."
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask why you don't make the anchor at the uppermost corner (top or bottom - doesn't matter) and then build your view from that?  That's what I do and that's below:  Sorry - I can't post pics yet.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/anchor"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
      android:text="Anchor point."
    />
   <TextView android:id="@+id/dependent"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/anchor"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@id/anchor"
      android:text="Dependent."
    />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Alternatively, if you really want to keep things as they are, just change the alignment of dependent to android:layout_alignParentTop="true".  You can have margin here as well to affect it's placement.  Here's the code and pic.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"    >

 <TextView android:id="@+id/anchor"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
   android:text="Anchor point."
  />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/dependent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:text="Dependent."
  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Using the top or bottom of the parent as the anchor is not what I want by using the RelativeLayout. Say we're making a facebook-like comment where there's the username as Dependent and the comment as Content, when there's a layout alignment I wouldn't want to change the margins of every single view I have. Only the anchor and the rest should follow..

Comment: Btw I couldn't see the difference between your code and mine except the layout_below and layout_alignLeft. They should give the same result as mine, only slightly different.

Comment: In the above code nothing disappears off screen.  No problems with dependent getting lost.  I don't follow your comment "Say we're making a facebook-like comment where there's the username as Dependent and the comment as Content, when there's a layout alignment I wouldn't want to change the margins of every single view I have. Only the anchor and the rest should follow."

Comment: see my answer below about creating an anchor button.  Everything alighned with the button moves when the button moves